# php:two calendar is not showing

Tags: php, javascript

Two calendar is not showing in one php file. scenario is below

I have a php file name `temp`. Here i want to show two calendar(previous month and next month).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html >

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="left1"><?php include('calendar_previous.php');?></div>

<div id="right1"><?php include('calendar_next.php');?>hello</div>

</body>

</html>
```

My `calendar_previous.php` is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="css/datetimepicker_css.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

<title>BuildUp Real Estate</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.1.4.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jsDatePick_prev.jquery.min.1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){

    g_globalObject = new JsDatePick({

        useMode:1,

        isStripped:true,

        target:"inputField1"

    }); 

    g_globalObject.setOnSelectedDelegate(function(){

        var obj = g_globalObject.getSelectedDay();

        alert("a date was just selected and the date is : " + obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year);

        document.getElementById("div3_example_result").innerHTML = obj.day + "/" + obj.month + "/" + obj.year;

    });





};

</script>

</head>

<body>  

<div id="inputField1"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

My `calendar_next.php` is almost same to `calendar_previous.php` with two difference of javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.1.4.4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jsDatePick_next.jquery.min.1.3.js"></script>
```

When i call `calendar_previous.php` and `calendar_next.php` separately it is showing previous and next month properly. But when i include this two php file in `temp.php` in different `div` only one calendar is showing. I want to show two calendar in `temp.php` in different `div`.

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: have you applied target two separately like for 1 target:"inputField1" and for 2 target:"inputField2"

Comment: @keyuratcodebins.com targets are separate but not working

Comment: target should be separate and object of date picker should be separate like g_globalObject1 for page 1 and g_globalObject2 for page 2. hope this will help.

Comment: @keyuratcodebins.com target and g_globalObject are different but not working.Only next month is showing in proper div.previous month div is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because now you are having two `window.onload`. So, that might be troubling. What you can try is place the contents of both `window.onload` to the second page and try.

2nd problem could be jquery conflict.

For that follow this

```
$s = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now replace all of the `$` with `$s` in one of your files.

That should resolve your problem. Tell me if it doesn't.

Comment: and also try changing (set to two different ones) the id of the input fields in both calender_previous and calender_next as well as the name of the variables in which the instances of JSDatePick are stored.

Comment: @UmairKhan name of variable and input fields are now different name but not working.Only next month is showing in her div.